# Javascript SumOfTwo

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a function `getPairs` which gets array and sum as a param and returns all possible pairs. But I have a problem with their position in the array and deleting it in some different input param

```js
function getPairs (arr, sum) {
    if (!arr.length) return []

    const result = []
    const numObject = {}

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        numObject[arr[i]] = i;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const diff = sum - arr[i];

        if (numObject[diff] && numObject[diff] !== i) {
            result.push([diff, arr[i]])
            arr.splice(arr.indexOf(diff), 1)
            arr.splice(i, 1)
        }
    }


    return result
}
console.log(getPairs([], 0))
console.log(getPairs([22, 3, 5, 0, 2, 2], 5))
console.log(getPairs([-5, 33, 2, 2, 3, 5, 0, 10, 3], 5))
console.log(getPairs([5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5], 5))
console.log(getPairs([3, 3, 6, 0], 6))
/*
    input: ([22, 3, 5, 0, 2, 2], 5)
    resutls must be: [[3, 2], [5, 0]]
    i get:           [[2, 3], [3, 2]]

    input: ([-5, 33, 2, 2, 3, 5, 0, 10, 3], 5)
    resutls must be: [[-5, 10], [2, 3], [2, 3], [5, 0]]
    i get:           [[10, -5], [3, 2], [0, 5]]

    input: ([5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5], 5)
    resutls must be: [[5, 0], [5, 0], [5, 0]]
    i get:           [[0, 5], [0, 5], [0, 5]]

    input: ([3, 3, 6, 0], 6)
    resutls must be: [[3, 3], [6, 0]]
    i get:   [[3, 3], [6, 0]]
*/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in your code:

- `splice` will move subsequent values in `arr` to earlier indexes, and so your `numObject` is not mapping them correctly anymore -- it still refers to the old index for a given value. The solution is not to `splice` at all, but just render the value at those indexes invalid, with `undefined`.
- `numObject[diff]` as a condition in the `if` will give a false negative when that value is 0, i.e. meaning the value `diff` occurs at index 0.
- `numObject` can only have one index for one particular value, yet your input can have duplicates, so you'll overwrite previous information and only keep the last index where a certain value occurs. You can solve this by storing subarrays of indexes instead of a single index.
- As you want matches to occur only once, you might as well require that the second index is greater (not only different) from `i`. This will go well with the fix for the first point, since `undefined` is never greater than `i`.
- It may surprise the caller of your function that their array `arr` is mutated (via either `splice` or overwriting with `undefined`), so it may be better to take a copy first, and leave the original untouched.

Here is your code adapted accordingly:

```js
function getPairs (arr, sum) {
    if (!arr.length) return [];
    arr = [...arr]; // since we are going to wipe out values, let's copy it.
    const result = [];
    const numObject = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // Allow multiple matches for the same value:
        numObject[arr[i]] = (numObject[arr[i]] || []).concat(i);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const diff = sum - arr[i];

        // require the match to be after i, so it excludes undefined
        if (numObject[diff]?.[numObject[diff]?.length-1] > i) {
            result.push([arr[i], diff]); // order
            arr[numObject[diff].pop()] = arr[i] = undefined; // remove both values
        }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(getPairs([], 0));
console.log(getPairs([22, 3, 5, 0, 2, 2], 5));
console.log(getPairs([-5, 33, 2, 2, 3, 5, 0, 10, 3], 5));
console.log(getPairs([5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5], 5));
console.log(getPairs([3, 3, 6, 0], 6));
```

Comment: Thanks for your sollution but:
ERROR:
input: [0,5,5,5,0,0,5,5]  results: [[0,5],[0,5],[0,5],[0,5],[0,5]]  expected: [[5,0],[5,0],[5,0]]
----
ERROR:
input: [0,0,5,5,5,1]  results: [[0,5],[0,5],[0,5]]  expected: [[5,0],[5,0]]
----
ERROR:
input: [3,3,6,0,3,0,3]  results: [[3,3],[3,3],[3,3],[6,0],[6,0]]   expected: [[3,3],[6,0],[3,3]]
----

Comment: Why in the first case the first result should not be [0,5] ??

Comment: 0 cant be first, sorry my bad

Comment: And you misrepresent the results. The first case:  input: `[0,5,5,5,0,0,5,5], 5` results in  `[[0,5],[5,0],[5,0]]` with my code.

Comment: i changed if (numObject[diff]?.[numObject[diff]?.length-1] > i && arr[i] !== 0)  and this work perfect, thank

Comment: Even without that change, the results you mentioned in the first comment are not the results from my code. How did you get those? I just checked your second and third example, and my code returns the expected result. BTW: that change is wrong, since `arr[i] == 0` could be a valid case. The rule that it cannot be first sounds like an "ad hoc" rule. What is the logic behind that?

Comment: If you don't want zero to be first, then don't do it like that, but change the push to: `result.push([diff, arr[i]]);` so the order is opposite.

Comment: One potential concern: this modifies the original array, leaving holes.  Thus `let arr = [22, 3, 5, 0, 2, 2]; getPairs(arr, 5)` returns `[[3,2],[5,0]]` as expected, but now `arr` looks like `[22, undefined, undefined, undefined, 2, undefined]`.  This may not be of any concern, and it would be quite easy to fix, but it's worth noting.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Scott, I added the line that will prevent this side effect. The OP's code was already mutating `arr`, but it is better to have no side effects.

Comment: Interesting to see how different our answers are.  Yours is almost certainly more efficient, but I find my approach much more elegant.

Comment: Yes, interesting indeed. My answer focused on fixing the issues in the OP's code, and not change more than that. However, I find it a pity that JavaScript engines have not evolved yet to optimise *functional programming* code that heavily uses `.map`, spread and such. There must be room for improvement there (in the engines).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Binary Search like approach using two pointers (the input array will be have to be sorted though, so time complexity will be O(nlogn)

```
const getPairs = (arr,sum)=>{
    let low=0
    let high=arr.length-1;
    let pairs=[]
    arr.sort(function(a, b){return a-b})// Sort in Ascending for Binary Search
    while(low<high){
        if(arr[low]+arr[high]==sum){
            pairs.push([arr[low],arr[high]])
        }
        if(arr[low]+arr[high]>sum){
            high-=1
        }else{
            low+=1
        }
    }
    return pairs
}
```

If you want to get rid of duplicate pairs, you will have to add them to set or use an hashmap(object)

Comment: I can't sort this array, because I have in result
    resutls must be: [[5, 0], [5, 0], [5, 0]]
    i get:                   [[0, 5], [0, 5], [0, 5]]

Comment: its a quick hack,change `pairs.push([arr[low],arr[high]])` to `pairs.push([arr[high],arr[low]])`, than you will get in the descending order (inside each pair)

Comment: it's work only in this case, but not for 
    input: ([-5, 33, 2, 2, 3, 5, 0, 10, 3], 5)
    resutls must be: [[-5, 10], [2, 3], [2, 3], [5, 0]]
    i get:           [[10, -5], [3, 2], [0, 5]]

Comment: Sorting probably cannot work, as the answers seem to involve finding the first value that can start a pair and then the first value that will complete it, removing both of them and continuing.  So the order in the initial array matters.

Answer (score 0):

Full code to solve this problem:

```
function getPairs (arr, sum) {
        if (!arr.length) return [];

        const result = [];
        const numObject = {};

        if (arr[0] === 0) {
            for(let i = arr.length - 1, j = i; i >= 0; i--) {
                if(arr[i] == 0){
                    let k = i, tmp = arr[i];
    
                    while(k < j)
                        arr[k] = arr[++k];
                        arr[j--] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            numObject[arr[i]] = (numObject[arr[i]] || []).concat(i);
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            const diff = sum - arr[i];

            if (numObject[diff]?.[numObject[diff]?.length-1] > i && arr[i] !== 0) {
                result.push([arr[i], diff]);
                arr[numObject[diff].pop()] = arr[i] = undefined;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Thanks, @trincot to help to solve it!

Answer (score 0):

From your examples, it looks as though what you are supposed to do is use a number in the array only once.  So to my mind the easiest way to do this is to find the index of the complement of the first number, and if it's non-negative, use that as a pair, recurring on the remainder of the array less the two values used.  If it's `-1`, then we didn't find a match for the first number, so we just recur on the remaining array.  Our recursion bottoms out when the list of numbers is empty and we just return an empty array.

It might look like this:

```js
const getPairs = ([x, ...xs], total, i = xs .indexOf (total - x)) =>
  x == undefined
    ? []
  : i > -1
    ? [[x, total - x], ... getPairs ([... xs .slice (0, i), ... xs .slice (i + 1)], total)]
  : getPairs (xs, total)


console .log (getPairs ([], 0))
console .log (getPairs ([22, 3, 5, 0, 2, 2], 5))
console .log (getPairs ([-5, 33, 2, 2, 3, 5, 0, 10, 3], 5))
console .log (getPairs ([5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5], 5))
console .log (getPairs ([3, 3, 6, 0], 6))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We might want to use a simple helper function that excludes an index:

```js
const excluding = (i) => (xs) =>
  [... xs .slice (0, i), ... xs .slice (i + 1)]
```

and rewrite the relevant line like this:

```js
    ? [[x, total - x], ... getPairs (excluding (i) (xs), total)]
```

---

**Note**: I'm assuming this is a homework problem.  Those are allowed on StackOverflow, but next time, please mention this in the question.